# export 'store' (imported as 'store') was not found in './app/store' (possible exports: default)

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, redux

**index.js file:**

```
 import React from 'react';
    import { createRoot } from 'react-dom/client';
    import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
    import { store } from './app/store';
    import App from './App';
    import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';
    import './index.css';
    
    const container = document.getElementById('root');
    const root = createRoot(container);
    
    root.render(
      <React.StrictMode>
        <Provider store={store}>
          <App />
        </Provider>
      </React.StrictMode>
    );
    
    
    reportWebVitals();
```

**store.js file:**

```
import { configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import userReducer from '../features/userSlice';



export default configureStore({
  reducer: {
    user: userReducer,
  },
});
```

> ERROR:- ERROR in ./src/index.js 16:11-16
>
> export 'store' (imported as 'store') was not found in './app/store'
> (possible exports: default)

Answer (score 4):

You export store as default export you need to import it as default

index.js

```js
 import React from 'react';
    import { createRoot } from 'react-dom/client';
    import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
    import store from './app/store';
    import App from './App';
    import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';
    import './index.css';
    
    const container = document.getElementById('root');
    const root = createRoot(container);
    
    root.render(
      <React.StrictMode>
        <Provider store={store}>
          <App />
        </Provider>
      </React.StrictMode>
    );
    
    
    reportWebVitals();
```

Answer (score 2):

You are wrong coming from two reasons:

**Reason number one:** you already export the `store` as **default** and you import it with `{}` the first thing you should remove is the `{}`. to be like below:

```
import store from './app/store';
```

**Reason number one:**

Write `store` in **capital letters** to be Store finally to be like below:

```
import Store from './app/store';
```